# async hooks in Vue component

Tags: vue.js, async-await, vuejs2

I want to use `await` keyword and synchronous code style inside Vue component lifecycle hooks, like `created`, `modified` etc... That requires those methods to be declared as `async`. In turns, that means that the hooks will return promises.

I didn't see an example with such approach anywhere before.

Is there any drawback to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Vue doesn't care what you do in the lifecycle hooks. They do not normally have any return value, as nothing calls them expecting a return value, so if you are expecting to use the promises they return, you will have to arrange that yourself.